# Trying to install jdk 8.0 in ubuntu 16.04 but getting error

Tags: software-installation, java

When I try to install jdk 8.0, I am getting everytime the same error:

```
download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing it from command-line, manually download and install the JDK package. Here is how:

1. Download appropriate JDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (.tar.gz).

   *Before the file can be downloaded, you must accept the license agreement. The archive binary can be installed by anyone (not only root users), in any location that you can write to. However, only the root user can install the JDK into the system location.*
2. Change directory to the location where you would like the JDK to be installed, then move the .tar.gz archive binary to the current directory.
3. Unpack the tarball and install the JDK, type in: `% tar zxvf jdk-8uversion-linux-x64.tar.gz`

   *The Java Development Kit files are installed in a directory called jdk1.8.0_version in the current directory.*
4. Delete the .tar.gz file if you want to save disk space.

To know more, visit: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html